# Unity WebGl build failed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

I changed my project to WebGL and I cant build it.
first error:Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!

Failed running "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe" --convert-to-cpp --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="WebGL" --architecture="EmscriptenJavaScript" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="C:\Users\peper\Desktop\게임\루트구~1\DEFENS~1\Assets /../Temp/StagingArea/Data\Native\build.bc" --cachedirectory="C:\Users\peper\Desktop\게임\루트구~1\DEFENS~1\Assets..\Library/il2cpp_cache" --compiler-flags="-Oz -DIL2CPP_EXCEPTION_DISABLED=1 " --emit-method-map --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AccessibilityModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AIModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AndroidJNIModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AnimationModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AssetBundleModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AudioModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ClothModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_CoreModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_CrashReportingModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_DirectorModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_DSPGraphModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_GameCenterModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_GridModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_HotReloadModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ImageConversionModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_IMGUIModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_InputLegacyModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_InputModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_JSONSerializeModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_LocalizationModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ParticleSystemModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_PerformanceReportingModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_Physics2DModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_PhysicsModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ProfilerModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ScreenCaptureModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SharedInternalsModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SpriteMaskModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SpriteShapeModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_StreamingModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SubstanceModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SubsystemsModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_TerrainModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_TerrainPhysicsModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_TextCoreModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_TextRenderingModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_TilemapModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_TLSModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UIElementsModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UIModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UmbraModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UNETModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityAnalyticsModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityConnectModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityTestProtocolModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityWebRequestAssetBundleModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityWebRequestAudioModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityWebRequestModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityWebRequestTextureModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_UnityWebRequestWWWModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_VehiclesModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_VFXModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_VideoModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_VRModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_WebGLModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_WindModule_Dynamic.bc" --additional-libraries="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_XRModule_Dynamic.bc" --profiler-report --map-file-parser="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.18f1/Editor/Data/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe" --directory="C:/Users/peper/Desktop/게임/루트구구 유니티콜라보레이트/Defense Route/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed" --generatedcppdir="C:/Users/peper/Desktop/게임/루트구구 유니티콜라보레이트/Defense Route/Temp/StagingArea/Data/il2cppOutput"

stdout:
Building build.bc with EmscriptenToolChain
Output directory: C:\Users\peper\Desktop\����\��Ʈ��~1\DEFENS~1\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Native
Cache directory: C:\Users\peper\Desktop\����\��Ʈ��~1\DEFENS~1\Library\il2cpp_cache
ObjectFiles: 208 of which compiled: 0
Total compilation time: 368 milliseconds.
Response file: C:\Users\peper\AppData\Local\Temp_1378387942\response.rsp
Response file: C:\Users\peper\AppData\Local\Temp_1647625708\response.rsp
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten_Win\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\python.exe" -E "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc" -o "C:\Users\peper\Desktop\����\��Ʈ��~1\DEFENS~1\Library\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_5A1DA1B9F57D02B4872EDCAF02B99A7C\build.bc" -s TOTAL_MEMORY=384MB -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 -s WASM=0 -O3 "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AccessibilityModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AIModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AndroidJNIModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AnimationModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AssetBundleModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AudioModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ClothModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_CoreModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_CrashReportingModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_DirectorModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_DSPGraphModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_GameCenterModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_GridModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_HotReloadModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ImageConversionModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_IMGUIModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_InputLegacyModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_InputModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_JSONSerializeModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_LocalizationModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ParticleSystemModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_PerformanceReportingModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_Physics2DModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_PhysicsModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ProfilerModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_ScreenCaptureModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_SharedInternalsModule_Dynamic.bc" "C:\Program F

second error: UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002bf] in :0
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in :0
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

can anyone explain what the problem is?
I read some articles but those did not help.

Comment: Any else errors in log after this message?

Comment: @selezen88 if anything they should be **before** these messages

Comment: @selezen88 do you mean before the build?

Comment: @derHugo do you know what is causing these problems?

Comment: Are there really no other errors before? Is it possible that the compiler doesn't like these asian characters so much? Did you try to use another project/folder name?

Comment: Just to be sure: before starting building You clear logs and after build stops You cant see any other error log messages, isnt it?

Comment: And what is Your build path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

did not add scene to the build.
I think thats why.